# Use JSON Object for Function Pointer Mapping in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to learn Socket.io and I'm a beginner in NodeJS.

I'm using `JSON` object as a kind of key-value store for mapping callback function with relevant event names. May be there is some other alternative to do it efficiently which I don't know. The problem is in the code below, when I call `bob.printName()` it prints the `JSON` object perfectly. But when I call the same function using the `callbacks['connection']()`, it says the `JSON` object is undefined. I would like to know the reason of that and also love to know any other efficient alternatives like PHP like array indexing.

```
/***
** index.js
***/

var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


var User = require('./User');
var bob = new User();

var callbacks = {
    'connection': bob.printName
};

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    bob.printName();
    callbacks['connection']();
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});


/***
** User.js
***/

var jsonObj = null;

function User() {

    this.jsonObj = {
        type: 'type',
        body: 'body'
    };
}

User.prototype.printName = function(){
    console.log(this.jsonObj);
}

module.exports = User;
```

Comment: Try `'connection': bob.printName.bind(bob)`

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON object", and what you have doesn't have anything to do with JSON.

Comment: @Pointy: That solved the problem. Thank you. Can you tell me what is wrong with the previous approach. May be some links?

Comment: @azizulhakim I was looking for a good duplicate question but couldn't find one. This is a common problem. The issue is that JavaScript functions have no real "link" to any object, even when an object property refers to the function. So when you use just `bob.printName` as a reference when setting up a callback, then when the callback is later called by the system the fact that you found the function as a property of the "bob" object is completely lost, so the `this` value in the function is wrong. The `.bind()` mechanism lets you "freeze" the `this` reference.